# windows 7: multithread process is not using all cores; task manager displays idle CPUs

Tags: windows-7, cpu, processor, multithreading, multicore

I made a little program that forks many threads; each thread performs some dummy calculations just to consume CPU (e. g.: sums 100000 functions of a counter, then prints the result to a logger). Running it on certain machines (e. g.: Intel Xeon, 12 cores), the behavior is correct, with all CPUs working at 100%, but when I launch it on my Intel I7, in Task manager I can clearly see 8 cores, but only 5 or 6 of them show some activity. I searched a bit on the net, but no found solution seems to have effect (attempts to unpark cores, etc.). How can I wake those idle cores up?

Comment: Which Intel i7 do you have? What temperature is it hitting?

Comment: Doesn't happen on my i7/Vista 64.  If I start 8 CPU-threads, all 8 cores go to 100%.  1000000 iterations sounds a bit low - try 10000000 to make sure that the logger operations are more infrequent - maybe blocking on logger input queue?

Comment: Thanks, you are definitely right: significantly increasing the number of iterations, I can see all CPUs going to 100%. Weird to note that on the 12-cores processor, all CPUs work at the same time, maybe at a low percentage, while on the 8-cores, some CPUs work at full speed, while some are completely idle.